# how to scale animate android text view to the right

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to have text come in from the left hand side of the screen, and when it gets to its position I want the text to scale towards the right side of the TextView.
This is the animation file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- This is where the view moves onto the screen -->
<translate
android:fromXDelta="-200%"
android:toXDelta="0%"
android:fromYDelta="0%"
android:toYDelta="0%"
android:duration="1000"
android:zAdjustment="top" ></translate>
<!-- this is where I am scaling the text it currently aligns on the left side of the textview -->
<scale
android:fromXScale="1.0"
android:fromYScale="1.0"
android:toXScale=".2"
android:startOffset="500"
android:toYScale="1.0"
android:duration="1000"></scale>
<!-- I am then trying to make the text bounce over the left side of the textview -->
<scale
android:fromXScale="1.0"
android:fromYScale="1.0"
android:toXScale="7.0"
android:startOffset="1500"
android:toYScale="1.0"
android:duration="200"></scale>
<!-- I am then resetting the text to its original size -->
<scale
android:fromXScale="1.4"
android:fromYScale="1.0"
android:toXScale="1.0"
android:toYScale="1.0"
android:startOffset="1700"
android:duration="50"></scale>
 </set>
```

I am also doing this for when text comes in from the right side and that works fine.
This is where the textViews are in the layout

```
    <TextView android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textSize="50dip" android:layout_marginTop="40dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="right" android:id="@+id/btnN" android:text="@string/play" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"></TextView>

    <TextView android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:layout_marginBottom="40dip" android:textSize="50dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="right" android:id="@+id/btnO" android:text="@string/option" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/btnI" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/info" android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:layout_marginRight="50dip" android:layout_marginTop="40dip" android:textSize="50dip" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/btnE" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:text="@string/exit" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginBottom="40dip" android:layout_marginRight="50dip" android:textSize="50dip"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
btnN and btnO are the ones I need to do this animation for
```

Comment: Please provide a question. What exactly doesn't work and how doesn't it work correct?

Comment: Try adding `android:gravity="right"` to the text that you want to scale towards the right side. This will align the text on the right hand side of the view.

Answer (score 1):

set `android:pivotX="100%"` to scale in your animation XML file.

And in java file:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.yourAnimation);
yourTextView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the file in a new folder res/anim.

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.urAnimation);
urTextView.setAnimation(animation); or urTextView.startAnimation(animation);
```

As u require.